# Resource limits on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, posix, ulimit, setrlimit

What are the Windows equivalents to the resource limit mechanisms exposed on Unix systems by Python's [`resource`](http://docs.python.org/library/resource.html) module, and POSIX [`setrlimit`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setrlimit)?

Specifically, I'm limiting processor time for a child process to several seconds. If it hasn't completed within the constraint, it's terminated.

Comment: It doesn't exist in Windows to my knowledge. The closest you can probably get is a job (introduced with Windows 2000) that you control from your own process. Resource limits in the way SUS defines them do not exist in Windows, though.

Comment: BTW: have a look at Process Lasso. It may be in part what you're interested in. Question is whether it provides all you need ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no portable way of getting information about the amount of processor time used by a child process in Python. But what `subprocess` module does (assuming you're starting the child with `subprocess.Popen`, which is recommended) give you is the process ID of the child process in `Popen.pid`. What you could do on Windows is run `tasklist` (see [manual](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491010.aspx)) using `subprocess.check_output` repeatedly and extract the info about the child proces from its output, using the PID as a filter.

As soon as the child process has has enough CPU time and if you used `subprocess.Popen()` to start the child process, you could use the `Popen.kill` method to kill it.

But I think it would be easier to kill the child process after after a specified number of seconds of wall time using a timer. Because if the child process hangs without using CPU time (for whatever reason), so does your python program that is waiting for it to consume CPU time.